# PloT/Graph decoration

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d, legending

[image: 1]I want this kind of picture in Mathematica with a transparent background of the ellipse such that the orange line also will appear. I tried it in the drawing tool but I am not getting the transparent background. Kindly let me know about it.

Comment: Can you please provide Mathematica code for what you have tried so far?

Comment: I have done this in powerpoint and in Mathematica I have not changed the coding for adding the ellipse, I just used the drawing tool options like ellipse., but I am not getting the transparent background

Answer (score 5):

- Use `Scaled[{.5, .5}]` to locate the `Circle` and `Text` at the center.
- And use `Rotate` to `Circle` and use the third parametic of `Text` to rotate text respectly.

```
Plot[x, {x, 0, 200}, Frame -> True, 
 Epilog -> {Rotate[Circle[Scaled[{.5, .5}], {25, 10}], 45 Degree], 
   Text[Style["Julie", 20, Red, Bold], Scaled[{.5, .5}], 
    Automatic, {1, .5}]}]
```

[image]